# Troubleshooting Windows XP "RestrictRun" policies

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, troubleshooting

I'm at a site where user accounts are limited to running only certain programs (according to file name), through the Windows XP `RestrictRun` policy mechanism.  I realize this is largely useless as a security mechanism, but it is what it is.

Occasionally we'll run into a situation where something under a user account triggers the usual error message: "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer", but running the same program under a unrestricted account doesn't give any insight into what program was trying to be launched.

In the interest of troubleshooting this type of scenario, is there a way to get Windows to log program names blocked by a user's `RestrictRun` policy, or to show the name of the program blocked when displaying the above error message?

Comment: And nothing is showing up in the machines Event Logs?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the Event Logs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find what threads/processes are related to the exe you are troubleshooting.  Once you know what other EXEs are required to run a given app you can more easily unblock it.

Comment: Thanks for the response – although a little bit of work this is the best approach I've heard. The telltale sign in procmon is the parent process reading an executable file, followed by RegEnumValue operations under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\RestrictRun`.